# Restoring database from script

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I have created a small scrip to restore databases from backups. Once the script is run it displays

> RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 28818 pages in 1.568 seconds
>   (143.584 MB/sec).

I have more code to alter the database, alter a few views and sp too but I am getting the following error; User does not have permission to alter database 'GreyGoo', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.

I have noticed too that I cannot see the database in the object explorer

this is what I use to restore the DB from a backup

1. if DB exists set to a single user
2. if DB exist drop database
3. Ran the below script

```
RESTORE DATABASE GreyGoo FROM DISK = 'C:\Bkp\GreyGoo_backup_2020_03_02_180002_5403592.bak'
WITH 
MOVE 'GreyGoo' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GreyGoo.mdf',
MOVE 'GreyGoo_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GreyGoo.ldf', 
REPLACE;
```

4. set DB to multi-users and other properties

So what is the problem and how can I solve it, I am currently testing my code on SQL Server 2008

Thanks

Comment: Just because you've restored the database doesn't mean you have access to it. If you restored a database where the `LOGIN` you are using doesn't have a `USER` mapped to it, and it doesn't have `sysadmin` privileges, you won't be able to access the database you restored. That is an intentional feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During your restore process, you will need to ensure your

1. login / permissions are correct.
2. if another previous database with same name is not there, if so delete it. Perhaps from a previous attempt
3. You can also turn off recovery option like below, recovery is  default
4. RESTORE FILELISTONLY

---

Sample -- [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-database-to-a-new-location-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
USE master;  
GO  
-- First determine the number and names of the files in the backup.  
-- AdventureWorks2012_Backup is the name of the backup device.  
RESTORE FILELISTONLY  
   FROM AdventureWorks2012_Backup;  
-- Restore the files for MyAdvWorks.  
RESTORE DATABASE MyAdvWorks  
   FROM AdventureWorks2012_Backup  
   WITH RECOVERY,  
   MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Data' TO 'D:\MyData\MyAdvWorks_Data.mdf',   
   MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Log' TO 'F:\MyLog\MyAdvWorks_Log.ldf';  
GO
```

Comment: I do have sysadmin rights, tried with the restore FILELISTONLY and work good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'MYDB'
GO
USE [master]
GO
/* Database [MYDB]  */
DROP DATABASE [MYDB]
GO

USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [MYDB] FROM  DISK = N'E:\FTP\local_MYDB_01.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'blank' TO N'E:\DBs\2019\MYDB.mdf',  MOVE N'blank_log' TO N'E:\DBs\2019\MYDB.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
GO
```